# I have called an image from Active Storage with url_for. Is there any way, to link that image with the post that belong to? in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have this call for the image from Active Storage, using url_for

```
 <% @posts.each do |post| %>
   <div class="card-group card-group-size">
     <div class="card recipes recipes_posts">
       <img src="<%= url_for(post.image) if post.image.attached?  %> " class="index_images">
       <div class="card-body">
         <h5 class="card-title"><%=link_to post.title, post, class: "post_title"%></h5>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
   <% end %>
```

This was the only way to call it there (/post/index.html.erb).
 I could call the same image with `<%= image_tag @post.image, class: "image_view" %>` in posts/show.html.erb, but this wont work on any other page.

i dont have any issues with the loading of the image, that work as is should, i only wish to know if i can make onclick that image to link to the post that belongs.

thank you

Comment: Do you want to create link on the image?

Comment: yes, i want to click that image and take me to the post that belongs to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your image in link tag passing link to `show` action. I assume there is a routes configure and available as helper `post_path`

```
<%= link_to post_path(post) do %>
  <%= image_tag post.image, class="index_images" if post.image.attached? %>
<% end %>
```